# ImageMagick crop non-square area of an image

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I'm having trouble with the crop tool in iMagick.

Right now my code looks like this

`$image->cropImage($width, $height, $x, $y);`

So the cropped object is inevitably going to be square. But what if I want to set 4 different points and get non-square object?

As you can see, currently I'm setting only the top left corner of the soon-to-be cropped image with `$x` and `$y`. Can I set the other 3 as well?

Comment: You would need to make a "mask" and I have no idea how to do that in Imagick. You might find an answer here: https://phpimagick.com/

Comment: You would have to compute the width and height from your four points and use that in cropImage()

Comment: @fmw42 but what if I need a trapezoid and not a rectangle?

Comment: You cannot crop in any other shape but a rectangle. For other situations, you can only crop the bounding rectangle and make the outside regions transparent.

Comment: @fmw42 but that's what I'm trying to achieve. I want a non-rectangle shape and the outside region transparent. How can I do that?

Comment: You make a mask by drawing a white filled polygon on a black background. Then put the mask into the alpha channel of the image. Sorry, I only know command line. But see -draw "polygon x1,y1 ... xn,yn" at https://imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/#primitives (which uses all 4 of your corner points) and https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagickdraw.polygon.php and convert ... -compose copy_opacity -composite to put the mask into the alpha channel. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#compose and  https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.compositeimage.php with imagick::COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY

Comment: @fmw42 wow. How did I not think about it myself... Thank you very much for helping. If you write an answer, I'll accept it. Have a great day!